# How do I pass data from time and combo box fields to MySQL via ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, datetime, combobox

I'm working on a personl project using PHP, ajax JS and MySQL (phpMyAdmin). I'm trying to implement an "Add URL" function that takes input data from an HTML form and submits to to my database via and ajax function so a full page refresh is not needed.

MY QUESTION IS: How do I write the ajax that selects the values from the "time" input field and the "combo box" input fields?

CODE:

insert function (ajax):

```
function insert() 
{
    var name= encodeURI(document.getElementById('name').value);
    var url= encodeURI(document.getElementById('name').value);

    //What code goes here so I can retrieve the data from the combo boxes and the time field from the input form???


    xmlhttp.open('get', 'addUrl.php?name='+name+'& releaseTime=' +releaseTime+'& releaseDay=' +releaseDay+'& category=' +category+'& genre=' +genre+'& url=' +url);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = contactAdded;
    document.getElementById("content02").innerHTML = "<center><img src='../Images/ajaxloading.gif' alt='Loading: Please Wait...'/></center>";
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    return;
}
```

addUrlForm.php:

```
    <!-- Include AJAX Framework -->
<script src="js/ajax.js" language="javascript"></script>

<?php

$addURL = $_GET['addURL'];

echo "Add URL:";
echo "<form action='javascript:insert()' method='get'>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Name:</td><td><input name='name' type='text' id='name' value='' size'30'></input></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Release Time:</td><td><input name='releaseTime' type='time' id='releaseTime' value=''></input></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Release Day:</td><td><select name='releaseDay' id='releaseDay'> <option value='monday'>Monday</option> <option value='tuesday'>Tuesday</option> <option value='wednesday'>Wednesday</option> <option value='thursday'>Thursday</option> <option value='friday'>Friday</option> <option value='saturday'>Saturday</option> <option value='sunday'>Sunday</option> </select></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<td>Category:</td><td><select name='category' id='category'> <option value='television'>Television</option> <option value='movie'>Movie</option> <option value='music'>Music</option> </select></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>Genre:</td><td><select name='genre' id='genre'> <option value='action'>Action</option> <option value='drama'>Drama</option> <option value='comedy'>Comedy</option> <option value='thriller'>Thriller</option> <option value='horror'>Horror</option> <option value='childrens'>Childrens</option> <option value='romantic'>Romantic</option> </select></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>URL:</td><td><input name='url' type='text' id='url' value='' size'250'></input></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table><br />";
echo "<input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Add URL'/>";
echo "</FORM>";

?>
```

addUrl.php, that send data to database:

```
    <?php include('config.php'); ?>

<?php

    $name = $_GET["name"];
    $releaseTime = $_GET["releaseTime"];
    $releaseDay = $_GET["releaseDay"];
    $category = $_GET["category"];
    $genre = $_GET["genre"];
    $url = $_GET["url"];

$insertContact_sql = "INSERT INTO `links` (`name`, `releaseTime`, `releaseDay`, `category`, `genre`, `url`) VALUES ('{$name}' , '{$releaseTime}' , '{$releaseDay}' , '{$category}' , '{$genre}' , '{$url}')";

$insertContact= mysql_query($insertContact_sql) or die(mysql_error());

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var releaseTime = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('releaseTime').value);
var releaseDay = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('releaseDay').value);
```

and so on for other fields.

If you need to support old browsers, you get the value of a SELECT with:

```
var releaseDaySel = document.getElementById('releaseDay');
var releaseDay = encodeURIComponent(releaseDaySel.options[releaseDaySel.selectedIndex].value);
```

BTW, you should be using `encodeURIComponent()`, not `encodeURI()`. And you also have the wrong ID in your assignment to `url`.

Comment: oh so I don't need to loop though the combo box options to see what one is selected? Thats how I had to do it in a similar project with radio buttons. I guess i was over thinking it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to do it in older browsers, which don't support `.value` of `<SELECT>` elements. You don't need a loop, but you do need to index the options.